# Memory Allocation with different struct types at once? (Valgrind proof)

Tags: c, memory, struct, minesweeper

Hi Stack Overflow Community,
I'm currently coding a minewsweeper game in C using structs.

The structs i use look like this:

```
typedef struct cell_s {
    bool isFlagged;
    bool isMine;
    bool isRevealed;
    //struct coordinates_s coordinates;
} cell;

typedef struct board_s {
    uint8_t width;
    uint8_t height;
    struct cell_s *cells;
} board;
```

to allocate memory, i use the following function:

`board *Minesweeper = initialize(10,10);`

which looks like this:

```
board *initialize(uint8_t height, uint8_t width){

    printf("[*] Allocating memory\n");
    uint8_t *game_memory = malloc(sizeof(board) + sizeof(cell) * width * height);
    printf("[*] creating Game Instance\n");
    board *Minesweeper = (board *)game_memory;

    //Initing Board Parameters
    printf("[*] setting parameters\n");
    Minesweeper->cells = (cell *)game_memory + sizeof(board);
    Minesweeper->width = width;
    Minesweeper->height = height;
    printf("[+] board width: %d\n",Minesweeper->width);
    printf("[+] board height: %d\n",Minesweeper->height);
    printf("[+] setting up cells");
    memset(Minesweeper->cells, 0, sizeof(cell) * width * height);

    return Minesweeper;
}
```

the program itself runs fine, but when checking with valgrind, it reports a lot of errors (mostly in the memset part of the cells) writing/reading in memory areas which are not allocated (will paste the valgrind output later).

I cannot spot the mistake.
Can somebody enlighten me, what i do wrong with allocation?

Edit:
Thanks so much for your reponses. As I'm still pretty new to programming in C, this helped me a lot.
I decided to rewrite the init function, and make it less complicated.
Also the valgrind errors have minimized now ;)

function *initialize looks now as:

```
board *initialize(uint8_t width, uint8_t height, uint8_t mineCount){
  printf("[*] Allocating memory\n");
  board *Minesweeper = malloc(sizeof(board));   // now only allocating memory for the board itself.
  printf("[*] setting parameters\n");
  Minesweeper->cells = calloc(width*height,sizeof(cell)); //calloc for the cells (+init ?)
  Minesweeper->width = width;
  Minesweeper->height = height;
  Minesweeper->mines = mineCount;
  printf("[+] board width: %d\n",Minesweeper->width);
  printf("[+] board height: %d\n",Minesweeper->height);
  printf("[+] Mines: %d\n",Minesweeper->mines);
  //placeMines(Minesweeper,mineCount);
  //getNeighborMines(Minesweeper); 
  return Minesweeper;
}
```

the valgrind output is now:

```
==14991== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14991==    at 0x109D52: DrawBoard (init.c:34)
==14991==    by 0x10992F: GameLoop (gamelogic.c:86)
==14991==    by 0x10A042: main (main.c:14)
==14991==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==14991==    at 0x483877F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==14991==    by 0x109BF7: initialize (init.c:7)
==14991==    by 0x10A01D: main (main.c:12)
==14991== 
01  _ _ _ _ _ 
02  _ _ _ _ _ 
03  _ _ _ _ _ 
04  _ _ _ _ _ 
05  _ _ _ _ _ 
Your Move: exit
[*] Memory free'd
==14991== 
==14991== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14991==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14991==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 2,164 bytes allocated
==14991== 
==14991== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14991== 
==14991== ERROR SUMMARY: 25 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==14991== 
==14991== 25 errors in context 1 of 1:
==14991== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14991==    at 0x109D52: DrawBoard (init.c:34)
==14991==    by 0x10992F: GameLoop (gamelogic.c:86)
==14991==    by 0x10A042: main (main.c:14)
==14991==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==14991==    at 0x483877F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==14991==    by 0x109BF7: initialize (init.c:7)
==14991==    by 0x10A01D: main (main.c:12)
==14991== 
==14991== ERROR SUMMARY: 25 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I suggest you read about [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). Then you don't need `cells` to be a pointer and you don't have to bother with pointer arithmetic or casting.

Comment: I also suggest you use [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) as that will "clear" (set to zero) the memory for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Minesweeper->cells = (cell *)game_memory + sizeof(board);
```

Type casts have a higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than addition, thus you want a set of parentheses here:

```
Minesweeper->cells = (cell *)(game_memory + sizeof(board));
```

Otherwise that `+ sizeof(board)` advances the pointer by more than `sizeof(board)` bytes ... actually by `sizeof(board) * sizeof(cell)`

I'm also not sure but I think you also need to make sure that memory is properly aligned ....

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer by myself.
I allocated the memory using `malloc`, but never was initializing it properly.
A simple `memset` afterwards now gives me no errors in valgrind.

Thanks all for your help and pointing me in the right direction.
Bet this was not the last post here ;)